# Is there is a command to move cursor?

Tags: dota-2

Is there is a command in Dota 2 to move cursor?

Can I send some coordinates to game to move my cursor?

Comment: Yeah, your mouse does that.  You may want to include why you're doing this so we can think about another way to solve it.

Comment: I WANT TO MAKE ITEM DROPPING BIND

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot move your mouse using DotA2 Console commands.

you can, however use

`(+/-)sixense_(left/right)_click`

and

`dota_camera_set_lookatpos x y`

to click and change the relative position your mouse is on the map.

for example, to queue a list of clicks at points on the map, you could place your cursor just under the timer, and press a bind which sets a specific set of coordinates, and then clicks for you, and possibly have this loop through lots of clicks.

Hope this helped.